# BackgroundWorker _ Exception not caught by The AppDomain.UnhandledException

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I m using the folowing code to handle exception from BackgroundWorker. The problem is that the exception is not propaged to the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.

App.xaml.cs:

`private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
            {
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
            }`

I have a pool of BackgroundWorker in the main App. Each BackgroundWorker represent a progress bar. The implementation of the DoWork is a follow:

```
 private void BackgroundWorker_EditIni(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Test");
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            FailureMessage = ex.Message;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            FailureMessage = DialogMessage.InternalError;
            e.Cancel = true;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` will [handle any unhandled exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the `DoWork` event handler. So if you just let the error get thrown (as you already are), then you should be able to get it in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event by checking `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Error` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.error%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which will be null if no exception was thrown.

I'm not entirely sure why you want this error to go to the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event handler, but if for some reason your error-handing and logging logic all lives in the event handler for the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event I'd suggest making a separate function that does that work which you could also call in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

```
if(e.Error != null)
{
    ErrorHandler.HandleCriticalError(e.Error);
}
```

Comment: Yes,  i get the exception in the RunWorkerCompleted event as follow:
`if (e.Error != null)
{
    PackagingDetail = "Fail";
    UploadingDetail = "Fail";
    Status = UploadStatus.Failed;

    throw e.Error;
}`

But, the error is not propaged AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException when i throw it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you want this error to go to the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event handler... see my edit. It may help you along.

Comment: exactly, all my logging logic is in the `AppDomain.UnhandledException`. And i don t want to put error logging logic in the Worker events.